# Why we are sure that $h^{'} $ is a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, cofibrations

Here is the proof that every cofibration is an embedding from "Introduction to homotopy theory" by Martin Arkowitz :

> [image]

My question is: Why we are sure that $h^{'}$ is a homomorphism? as that will imply that $f^{'}$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

I think it says $i’$ is a homeomorphism instead, and this is obvious by the definition of the domain and range of $i’$ (also note that $i’$ maps the elements in the domain to the same element in the range, as $i$ was defined as the *inclusion*). Now with this in our mind, we can conclude that $f’$ is also a homeomorphism.

Comment: I am speaking about $h^{'}.$ As we know that $i^{'}$ is a homeomorphism, so it must be a composition of 2 homeomorphisms ..... am I correct? so why $h^{'}$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: @Smart20 Yes. A composition of maps is a homeomorphism if and only if the composed maps themselves are also homeomorphisms.

Comment: I believe the term ‘cofibration’ is only applied to continuous maps.

Comment: So where is the answer to my question :)? @NoahSchweber .... why is $h^{'}$ a homeomorphism?

Comment: I believe that should be a consequence of the proof instead of given property.